# Stored Procedure to update a column values with a column of syscolumns

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I want to update a column ('n_tamanho') of a table that I created ('campo_sys') with the values of 'collength' from syscolumns.

For that I used this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()

DEFINE testecol smallint;

FOREACH cur1 WITH HOLD FOR

SELECT  collength
INTO    testecol
FROM    syscolumns

update campo_sys 
set campo_sys.n_tamanho = testecol;

END FOREACH

END PROCEDURE;
```

When comparing the values of collength and n_tamanho, the values are not the same. What could be wrong?

Comment: It might be helpful to give a specific example of a column definition and the two different values

Comment: After executing the procedure, I'm obtaining different values of collength and n_tamanho. For example, n_tamanho=20 and collength=2048, for the same record

Comment: it sounds like you're getting the difference between the potential maximum length of a varchar field and something the current longest value, although I'm not familiar enough with Informix to be certain

Answer (score 1):

When you issue the statement:

```
update campo_sys 
    set campo_sys.n_tamanho = testecol;
```

You are updating *all* rows in `campo_sys`.  Presumably, different rows of `syscolumns` have different lengths.  However, only the last one is going to be recorded -- as the value for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

As @gordon-linoff said, for every record on `syscolumns` you're updating all records on `campo_sys` .

You need to tell us if there is a way to identify uniquely each record across the tables.

If you are storing the original **tabid** has I suggested on the previously post and the **colno** you can do this simply by:

```
UPDATE campo_sys col1
SET col1.n_tamanho = (
    SELECT  col2.collength 
    FROM    syscolumns  col2
    WHERE   col2.tabid = col1.ns_tabela 
            AND  col2.colno = col1.ns_campo
);
```

If you kept your own id for the **tabid** and **colno** you can do something like:

```
UPDATE campo_sys col1
SET col1.n_tamanho = (
    SELECT  col2.collength 
    FROM    syscolumns  col2, tabela_sys tab1, systables tab2 
    WHERE   col1.ns_tabela = tab1.ns_tabela
            tab1.nome = tab2.tabname
            AND col2.tabid = tab2.tabid
            AND col2.colname = col1.nome
);
```

Again you're not telling the whole picture and you can do this easily just using view.

Bear in mind that we're here to help and we spent time doing so, don't edit your posts like you've done on the other one.

In the future other people may be looking for what you've asked and won't find an answer, remember that the answers given may not suite you but can help others. I will revert back you're edit.

If this, or the other, answer don't fit what you're looking for post the schemas of your tables and the complete requirements.